# Erro ao gerar arquivos/classes a partir de um Web Service com Netbeans

Tags: java, web-service, netbeans, wsdl

Estou tentando gerar arquivos/classe a partir de um Web Service e trazê-lo para meu projeto Java.

Para isto estou utilizando IDE Netbeans 8.0.2

Num primeiro momento estou recebendo a mensagem `"Uma classe/interface com o mesmo nome já está sendo usada. Use a personalização de classe para resolver este conflito."`

Durante minhas pesquisas encontrei um caso muito semelhante: https://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic45287.html

O link o autor indica que devo setar a propriedade `-b-xautoNameResolution` (com o valor true) (imagem abaixo) em opções `wsimport` e isto resolverá o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida o log me apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é, como o comando `-b-xautoNameResolution` não foi parar na linha de execução do `wsimport` (como mostra no log acima).

Com `wsimport` no prompt de comando consigo fazer isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente `value` como nome da opção e `-XautoNameResolution` como valor (sei que parece estranho, mas era assim em versões anteriores do Netbeans).

Comment: Ah, esqueci, isso é feito no painel do Jaxb, não do `wsimport`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos, a imagem abaixo mostra como resolver a pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Percebi que você usou -b (minúsculo) na interface do Netbeans e -B (maiúsculo) no terminal. Olhando a documentação do "wsimport" existe uma diferença na semântica destas duas opções e você realmente deve estar querendo a segunda: `-B<jaxbOption>`.

Seria este o problema?

Comment: O @Anthony Accioly respondeu esta pergunta no comentário abaixo da minha pergunta. Trata-se de um bug do netbeans. No campo opção coloquei value e no campo valor -XautoNameResolution no painel do wsimport. Vlww

Comment: Que bom @Eduardo. Mais uma peculiaridade de IDEs. Será que o Anthony (ou você mesmo) não poderiam criar uma resposta com o conteúdo correto? Aí depois você aceita a resposta para que a pergunta saia da lista de problemas sem solução do site. Abraço